# How to print only one match of grep when tail -f?

Tags: text-processing, grep

I'm reading an active log and trying to get some special calls

```
$ tail -f example.log | egrep 'pattern1|pattern2|pattern3|pattern4|pattern5'
```

But a couple of patterns barely are printed (due to the dev flow) and the other are very continuously printed.

How can I make `egrep` to only print one request for each pattern so I can easily see they are working great.

Comment: open 5 different `tail ... grep` sessions, one for each pattern?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yep, I know there could be multiple ways to do what I want but dealing with multiple sessions or multiple files. I'm looking for a ¿one-line? solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
tail -f example.log | awk '
  BEGIN {
    n = split("pattern1,pattern2,pattern3,pattern4,pattern5", pats, /,/)
  }
  {
    found=0
    for (i in pats) if ($0 ~ pats[i]) {
      found=1
      delete pats[i]
      n--
    }
  }
  found {print; if (!n) exit}'
```

Note that `awk` will exit as soon as it has seen all the patterns, but `tail` will only exit (of a SIGPIPE) only the next time it writes something after that.

Or if lines may not match several patterns and if you don't care about exiting when all patterns are found, shorter but less efficient:

```
awk '/pattern1/&&!a++ || /pattern2/&&!b++ || /pattern3/&&!c++ || \
     /pattern4/&&!d++ || /pattern5/&&!e++'
```

With `zsh` and GNU `grep`:

```
(trap '' PIPE;tail -f example.log > >(grep -m1 pattern1) \
                                  > >(grep -m1 pattern2) \
                                  > >(grep -m1 pattern3) \
                                  > >(grep -m1 pattern4) \
                                  > >(grep -m1 pattern5))
```

But note that lines matching multiple patterns will be printed as many times.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you're after `-o` which will print only the matched part.  Then you could do the following:

```
cat example.log | egrep -o 'pat1|pat2|pat3|pat4|pat5' | sort | uniq
```

If the output contains a pattern it is because at least one line matched that pattern.  If the output contains all 5 patterns, each pattern matched at least one line.

Does not work with regexes that can match different characters or different length matches.

Comment: Almost right with `-o` but replace: `cat example.log` with `tail -f example.log` and skip sort+uniq and this will work. If one want more than pattern use regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be to output the lines matching each pattern over the previous one on its own line like with:

```
#! /bin/sh -
tput rmam # no line wrap for terminals that can do it
awk -v u="$(tput cuu1)" -v el="$(tput el)" '
  BEGIN {
    for (n = 0; n < ARGC; n++) pat[n] = ARGV[n]
    ARGC=0
  }
  {
    pre = ""; post = el "\r" u
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
      if ($0 ~ pat[i]) print pre $0 post
      pre = pre "\n"
      post = post u
    }
  }
  END{printf "%s", pre}' "$@"
tput smam
```

Called as:

```
tail -f example.log | that-script pattern1 pattern2...
```

Example:

[image]