# only find unique results in grep

Tags: grep

I am grepping for few words in a file with this command

```
grep -iE "(foo|bar|test|something)" filename.txt
```

This works fine but it is finding ALL occurrences for the found words. So for example if `foo` is found 8 times it will show all 8 results.

Is it possible to show only unique results? Perhaps show the first one.

Comment: You can use `-o` and then perform `| sort | uniq`.  I made an [answer with such an example before](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/300119/172635)

Comment: Or even shorter add `|sort -u` after the grep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option to show only the first match.  Observe:

```
$ grep -iE "(foo|bar|test|something)" filename.txt
Foo 1
Bar 2
foo 3
Foo 4
```

Now, to restrict this to the first match, add `-m1`:

```
$ grep -iEm1 "(foo|bar|test|something)" filename.txt
Foo 1
```

A limitation is that this will show only the first match, not the first `foo` and also the first `bar`, etc.

#### Printing the first of several different matches

Consider this test file:

```
$ cat filename.txt
Foo 1
Bar 2
foo 3
Foo 4
test 5
test 6
```

To print the first match for each of the three regexes shown:

```
$ awk -v a='[fF]oo [bB]ar [tT]est' 'BEGIN{split(a,b," ")} {for (i in b) if ($0~b[i] && !c[i]) {print; c[i]++}}' filename.txt
Foo 1
Bar 2
test 5
```

This works by putting whatever regexes you want to match in the variable `a`.   `a` is split up into words and put in array `b`.  Each of the regexes in `b` is tested against each line and only the first match for each is printed.

Comment: Hmm that option isn't having an affect on my results. Is it because I have line as compared to multiple lines? `$ more test.txt
one two three one four five six 7 six` and grepping `$ grep -iEm1 "(one|six|five)" test.txt
one two three one four five six 7 six`

Comment: I see the limitation note you added. That won't work for my. I need something that shows first foo match, first bar match, etc.

Comment: @Anthony I have added code that I think does what you want: see updated answer.  (As for the `-m1` option, I can't tell from the comment (comments are unformatted) what happened but `-m` is supported by both GNU sed and OSX sed.)